# MySQL database connection through Pycharm on MacBook

Tags: python, mysql, macos, pycharm

Im currently attempting to follow a youtube tutorial on how to connect a database through Pycharm however it's not connecting and I'm not sure where the problem is or how I am able to solve it. the code is:

```py
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import errorcode

try:
    cnn = mysql.connector.connect(
        user='root',
        password='root',
        host='localhost',
        database='name')
    print("it works")
except mysql.connector.Error as e:
    if e.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
        print("something is wrong with username and password")
    elif e.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
        print("database does not exist")
    else:
        print("E")

cursor = cnn.cursor()
addName = "INSERT INTO name (fName, lName) values (%s, %s)"
fName = "Rae"
lName = "Smith"
empName = (fName, lName)

cursor.execute(addName, empName)

cnn.commit()
cursor.close()
cnn.close()
```

Once I run it I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
something is wrong with username and password
line 19, in <module>
    cursor = cnn.cursor()
NameError: name 'cnn' is not defined
```

I've seen the user on the tutorial receiving the same warning however when he runs his code there is no error like the one I receive.  How I may be able to solve this?

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what the problem is and where to look. On line 19, it says `cnn` is not defined.  You need to have `cnn` defined before line 19.

Comment: I at first assumed it was because I didn't define the cnn however the user I followed only had the same error as me when he changed the username and password (it was a 5 year old tutorial I guess thing have changed haha) I figured out the error came from the fact I included the username password and host however I didn't include the port. Thank you for your help though :)